# How to encode SQLite FTS3 strings

Tags: sqlite, fts3

I'm working with a SQLite FTS3 table as explained here: https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

I'm interested in the field end_block, described as:

> This field may contain either an integer or a text field consisting of
>   two integers separated by a space character (unicode codepoint 0x20).
>   The first, or only, integer is the blockid that corresponds to the
>   interior node with the largest blockid that belongs to this segment
>   b-tree. Or zero if the entire segment b-tree fits on the root node. If
>   it exists, this node is always an interior node.
>
> The second integer, if it is present, is the aggregate size of all
>   data stored on leaf pages in bytes. If the value is negative, then the
>   segment is the output of an unfinished incremental-merge operation,
>   and the absolute value is current size in bytes.

I'm trying to make a consistency checker to make sure some FTS3 tables haven't been modified.

I need a way to encode strings in FTS3 to get the block_number but haven't been able to find anything on the internet. Some example of encoding:

Good morning! How is it going? - 0 96

Everything is okey - 0 71

Okay I will get back to you once everything is in place - 0 167

EDIT: To clarify the question, what I really need is some method to input a string as "Everything is okey" and get the second integer of the end_block field (71).

Any idea?

Comment: Do you actually mean "decode"?

Comment: Well, it is not decode per se, I need to be able to replicate what fts3 does and get the block_size of different strings, maybe with a script or something like that.

Comment: In the question, you say you need to get the block_number. Please clarify what you actually want to do.

Comment: What I need is to input some text and get the second integer of the end_block field.

Comment: You have to check the structure of the segments (the B-trees). How exactly those look depends on how the table data was inserted; there is no unique correct value that depends on the text alone.

Comment: But there has to be some way to replicate the procedure and get the end_block parameters right? I could create a database and import things there... but that would be the worse way.

Comment: When you insert the same data in a different order, or with different DELETEs between them, you get different B-trees for the *same* data. You cannot replicate the same index; you can only check that the values are consistent.

Comment: Okay, that is exactly what I need, how could I check that the values are consistent? Is there any easy way to do it? Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144234/discussion-between-arnau-ec-and-cl).

Comment: All the data structures are described in the documentation you linked to.